# JavaScript Table not displaying

Tags: javascript, html-table, displayobject

I've made this table:

```
<button onclick="calc();">Display Results</button>
<table id='data' data-role="table" >
    
</table>
```

To take values from these sliders:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="points">Voltage (V)</label>
    <input type="range" name="points" id="volt" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="10">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label for="points">Minimum Resistance (&#8486)</label>
    <input type="range" name="points" id="resMin" value="50" min="100" max="1000" step="100">
</form>
<form method="post">
    <label for="points">Maximum Resistance (&#8486)</label>
    <input type="range" name="points" id="resMax" value="50" min="100" max="1000" step="100">
</form>
```

And this function:

```
function calc()
{   
    var volt=document.getElementById("volt").value;
    var resMin=document.getElementById("resMin").value;
    var resMax=document.getElementById("resMax").value;

    var table = document.getElementById("data");
    var header = table.createTHead();
    var row = header.insertRow(0);
    
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = "Voltage (V)";
    row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = "Resistance (&#8486)";
    row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = "Power (W)";
    

    for (var i = 0; i<= ((resMax - resMin)/100); i++)
    {
        table.insertRow(i+1);
        table.rows[i+1].insertCell(0);
        table.rows[i+1].insertCell(1);
        table.rows[i+1].insertCell(2);
        
        table.rows[i+1].cells[1].innerHTML = resMin + i*100;
        table.rows[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML = (Math.pow(volt,2)/resMin);
    }
    

}
```

But, I get no errors, and when I click the button, nothing happens.
The browser console is clean, there doesn't appear to be any syntax errors, and I can't seem to find a solution.

Full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Khalid Alzhrani
A00361007
Assignment #4
-->
<html>
  
  <head>
    <title>Chapter 4 - PE4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/display.js'>
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  
  <body>
      <div data-role ="header" data-theme="b" style="text-align:center;">
      Electricity<br>Calculator</div>
      
      
     <div data-role="content" class="ui-content">
        <form method="post">
            <label for="points">Voltage (V)</label>
            <input type="range" name="points" id="volt" value="0" min="0" max="1000" step="10">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="points">Minimum Resistance (&#8486)</label>
            <input type="range" name="points" id="resMin" value="50" min="100" max="1000" step="100">
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <label for="points">Maximum Resistance (&#8486)</label>
            <input type="range" name="points" id="resMax" value="50" min="100" max="1000" step="100">
        </form>
         
        <button onclick="calc();">Display Results</button>
        
        
        <table id='data' data-role="table" >
        
        </table>



    <div data-role = "footer" data-theme="b" style="text-align:center;">
        <small>Power Display</small><br>
      <small>Khalid Alzhrani - A00361007</small>  
    </div>
         
     </div>
      
  </body>
```

Comment: The html you've posted is incomplete. Where is `resMin` or`resMax`?

Comment: Updated. Didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors?

Comment: it's working https://jsfiddle.net/k1b1rzub/1/

Comment: @Yass Did you check my post for when I said the console is clean?

Comment: Sorry, just realised that now. I've also confirmed that your code is working via a fiddle.

Comment: @tanaydin I updated the post with the full HTML, the CSS is jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css, fairly standard. 

Can you see why it wouldn't display? I'd send you a link, but its only on my localhost right now.

Comment: please add some breakpoints or debugger; lines to your javascript codes to debug it. as I tested your code is working...

Answer (score 1):

Your variables: `volt`, `resMin` and `resMax` are the same names as the actual elements. If you attempt to access these variables from a scope other than where the variables are declared, you are actually accessing the objects themselves and therefore not getting their values because in JavaScript any element that has an `id` can be accessed in code through that global id name.

In addition, you should not use inline HTML event handlers as they create spaghetti code and create global wrapper functions around your callback code.

Lastly, you didn't have a line in there about the volt column in the new row.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fjnyrpm1/15/ that uses the DOM Event standard `addEventListener()` for wiring up events.

[image]

Comment: Its a working fiddle, but for some reason doesn't work in an actual webserver (XAMPP and Dreamweaver)
I also didn't have anything in the volt column because well, I didn't know if I was going to have all cells display the voltage, or just one big one with it written a single time.

Comment: All code in fiddle follows standards and should work everywhere. Have never heard of XAMPP.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work in dreamweiver. Would you like me to pastebin the code and show you? XAMP is just a standard LAMP stack. (more or less)

Comment: Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/ELrJG1MP & http://pastebin.com/0GWiZTRQ

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nictrasavios/6ejtzbh5/2/

Comment: @NictraSavios Don't you want to create the header row just once, no matter how many times a new entry is added?

Comment: @NictraSavios It is working for me when I run the code on my end, but is each click of the button supposed to create multiple rows (different resistances are shown for the inputted voltage)?  Please check my updated answer that includes picture of what I get with the code you posted running my my end.

Comment: The math is wrong, I already know that. I was trying to get the displaying of the content working before I fixed the math. For all it matters, they could say "1,2,3,4,5,6,"

I have since fixed the math on my end, but the display is still not working, which is the weirdest thing ever. In the JSfiddle I posted, it doesn't work either. 
Copying that JS fiddle, I got one error about "calc" not being there, fixed that, and it still isn't showing up.

Comment: Ok, but as I say, it's working for me and it uses all standards based code. I will say that I removed the links to jQuery to test because I was getting an error about jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Well, thank you for the help with DOM listeners, but since my problem stands, I can't exactly mark it as solved.